# Looping a section of code with different variables in python?

Tags: python, loops, variables

I am designing a quiz which has to save three different scores to a file. How would I loop this and are you able to change the variable names? For example, the first time it loops, score1, then score2 then score3.

Thanks For the help in advance

Comment: Can you show us your code and what have you tried otherwise it is very difficult to answer.

Comment: Is this homework, and have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary, with the three values indexed with keys, and change a variable who contains the current key's name.